# Wrong shadow on rendered object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

Cycles render incorrect shadows on default UV-Sphere when I shade smooth it. I used 2 different versions of the blender to test it but got the same result in both versions.
It looks like it renders both shade flat and shade smooth at the same time. Eevee shadows are correct.

How do I fix it? Reducing light won't help

**Cycles Shade Smooth:**[image]

**Cycles Shade Flat:**[image]

**Cycles Shade Flat Reduced Light:**[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? 2.9 mentions this in the release notes: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/render/cycles/object_settings/object_data.html#shading

Comment: @marcellothearcane  Blender 2.90.3 and Blender 2.82

Comment: @marcellothearcane It's a default UV-sphere, I got the same error with the default cube

Comment: @marcellothearcane link to my .blend file in the question

Comment: @lemon I don't have "shading" in my object [property panel](https://gyazo.com/b5136d9ead3f1861ae382c2181f63e8c)

Comment: @cxnt Version 2.90.1. I don't think it is possible before.

Comment: @lemon I've 2.90.3 version of Blender with [e-cycles](https://blendermarket.com/products/e-cycles), if that matters, but this problem also occurs for me when I'm on 2.82 version...

Comment: @lemon I've downloaded the latest version and image in your linked post fixed that problem for me. Thank you!